# Sound and call with whatsapp call and line call using loudspeaker while typing

Tags: ios, audio, whatsapp.app

I can't post a video but hopefully you guys will understand. When I try to make a call using the loudspeaker with WhatsApp or Line, the sound becomes weird, as if both the call sound and typing sounds are ringing together.

Has anyone else experienced this issue? If so, how do I fix it?

I just bought a new iPhone 11 Pro and it's doing this just like my previous iPhone XR.

Comment: Typing sounds can be turned off in settings -> sounds -> keyboard clicks. You can turn it off and try the call again. Also, welcome and please have a look at the quick [tour].

Comment: I know but i want to turn it on ... but why when i type it sounds weird